# How to setup Environment for Eslint in existing project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: .eslintrc.js:
Environment key "es2021" is unknown

```
at /Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:169:19
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validateEnvironment (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:163:30)
at validateConfigArray (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:334:9)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:417:13)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:271:21)
at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:951:18)
at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:868:38)
at lint (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:278:17)
at transform (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:252:18)
at /Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:127:18
at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/artic/Documents/RestroWorld/HRConsultancy/node_modules/loader-fs-cache/index.js:31:14)
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (node:fs:314:13)
```

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.

Comment: what is the content of your `.eslintrc.js`? Which version of `eslint` are you using?

Comment: module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/essential"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
It can be solved by simpley npx eslint --init :)